# Visual Studio 2008 Form Designer messes up boolean properties values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-forms-designer

I have a very annoying problem I'm trying to solve for couple of weeks. I have a WinForms C# project where I developed my custom control (ListView + ToolStrip with ToolStripButtons). This control is used in different forms inside solution - but in other projects. For different forms I need to make certain buttons visible or hidden, so I have added to my control corresponding properties like

```
    public Boolean DeleteButtonVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return tsbDelete.Visible;
        }
        set
        {
            tsbDelete.Visible = value;
        }
    }
```

Some buttons are visible by default, some are hidden. In designer when editing a form with my control I'm able to change those properties, buttons on control become visible or hidden as they should. But every time I'm changing *anything* in my control source file in *all* forms those properties are reset to default values regardless of what I have set in designer and I have to restore those values manually. Well, I'm using a source control so this is not that hard, but performing "Undo" on a couple dozen of files every time I change a bit in another file is a damn disaster.

I have tried to use [DesignerSerializationVisibility] attribute to fix this issue. If I used it with value "Hidden" it didn't do any good at all - values were just not saved. "Content" made buttons randomly disappear even if by default they were visible. "Visible" lead to no effect, as this is default value...

I don't want to set every button visibility for every form in my code - this is just not the way it should be done.

Does anyone know something about this?

Comment: Have you specified the default value on your properties using the [`DefaultValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx) attribute?  Or do you set these values in a constructor?  The designer will always honor default values provided by this attribute.

Comment: I have tried specifying default value this way and it works. The problem is that I can do that in control code while in forms that are using it I often need non-default values set in form's designer - and those values are lost when changing a single byte in control code.

Comment: As I understand it, if your properties have the default values specified by using this attribute, it will be rendered as having this value as long as you don't explicitly set it.  If the designer has to refresh the values, anything that isn't set explicitly will fall back to the default value.  Without the attribute, it might not be the default value that you want.  You should set both the default value in the constructor and the same value using the attribute.

Comment: @Jeff: I do understand this and I have tried what you suggest - and this is actually the problem I'm trying to solve) Those values are set in control constructor, set in DefaultValue attribute and then overwritten with non-default values in forms using my control. I **want** these values to stay non-default and explicitly set but designer forcibly cleans any overrides when I edit control code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Control.Visible property is special.  The getter does *not* return the last assigned value, it only returns true when the control is actually visible.  That can have side-effects, you've found one.  In this case probably induced when the control switches out of design mode.  To do this correctly, you must store the assigned state in a backing variable.  Like this:

```
    private bool tsbDeleteVisible;

    public bool DeleteButtonVisible {
        get { return tsbDeleteVisible; }
        set { tsbDelete.Visible = tsbDeleteVisible = value; }
    }
```

Be sure to initialize the default value of the backing variable to the default value of tsbDelete.Visible.  Use the constructor to be sure.

Comment: Thank you very much for this tip! It was really the thing I was missing. Everything started working OK after adding backing variables for my properties.